# Magento 2 rest api /V1/invoices/{id}/capture

Tags: rest-api, magento2.2.4

I am posting data using `/V1/invoices/{id}/capture` but it is returning 'Request does not match any route'.

I am posting base `url/rest/V1/invoices/5/capture` also I have tried `url/rest/default/V1/invoices/5/capture`.

Can anyone suggest where I am wrong?

Comment: Have you tried that in the browser?

Comment: yes, it is giving same message

Comment: Refer this [link](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4385)

Comment: @PratikOza it is a different issue, I am unable to call the api

Comment: @akshaybillore Please change request type from GET to POST and check again.

Comment: I want to test from browser only. Can you tell how can I define that in url?

Comment: I think this `url/rest/default/V1/invoices/5/capture` should return you permission error in the browser?

Comment: it is only returning Request does not match any route

Comment: @akshaybillore You need to use API development app like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to test request and response. Also, need to set headers for authentication to get response.

Comment: @PratikOza Thank you for tellinmg about postman, It is working with POST but now I am getting error '"Consumer is not authorized to access %resources"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try following steps:**

> 1. Install Postman Extension in chrome browser
> 2. Generate Token

```
Request Type: POST
URL: http://example.com/rest/V1/integration/admin/token

Body:
1. select raw
2. select JSON from last dropdown
3. Add this code in body {"username": "MAGENTO BACKEND USERNAME","password": "MAGENTO BACKEND PASSWORD"}

Response: TOKEN
```

> 3. Capture request

```
Request Type: POST
URL: http://example.com/rest/V1/invoices/1/capture

Headers:
1. Key: Content-Type | Value: application/json
2. Key: Authorization | Value: Bearer TOKEN
```

Comment: @akshaybillore Happy to help. Keep helping :)

Comment: @ Pratik Oza 
can u clarify me want do u mean by "1" in http://example.com/rest/V1/invoices/1/capture.
its order_id or any other and what should i pass in body of post request to get invoice

Comment: "The capture action is not available." i got this error,